# (pytorch / mse) How can I change the shape of tensor?

Tags: pytorch, mnist, mse

**Problem definition:**

I have to use `MSELoss` function to define the loss to classification problem. Therefore it keeps saying the error message regarding the shape of tensor.

**Entire error message:**

> torch.Size([32, 10]) torch.Size([32])
>   --------------------------------------------------------------------------- RuntimeError                              Traceback (most recent call
>   last)  in 
>        53     output = model.forward(images)
>        54     print(output.shape, labels.shape)
>   ---> 55     loss = criterion(output, labels)
>        56     loss.backward()
>        57     optimizer.step()
>
> /opt/conda/lib/python3.7/site-packages/torch/nn/modules/module.py in
>   **call**(self, *input, **kwargs)
>       530             result = self._slow_forward(*input, **kwargs)
>       531         else:
>   --> 532             result = self.forward(*input, **kwargs)
>       533         for hook in self._forward_hooks.values():
>       534             hook_result = hook(self, input, result)
>
> /opt/conda/lib/python3.7/site-packages/torch/nn/modules/loss.py in
>   forward(self, input, target)
>       429 
>       430     def forward(self, input, target):
>   --> 431         return F.mse_loss(input, target, reduction=self.reduction)
>       432 
>       433
>
> /opt/conda/lib/python3.7/site-packages/torch/nn/functional.py in
>   mse_loss(input, target, size_average, reduce, reduction)    2213
>   ret = torch.mean(ret) if reduction == 'mean' else torch.sum(ret)
>   2214     else:
>   -> 2215         expanded_input, expanded_target = torch.broadcast_tensors(input, target)    2216         ret =
>   torch._C._nn.mse_loss(expanded_input, expanded_target,
>   _Reduction.get_enum(reduction))    2217     return ret
>
> /opt/conda/lib/python3.7/site-packages/torch/functional.py in
>   broadcast_tensors(*tensors)
>        50                 [0, 1, 2]])
>        51     """
>   ---> 52     return torch._C._VariableFunctions.broadcast_tensors(tensors)
>        53 
>        54
>
> **> RuntimeError: The size of tensor a (10) must match the size of tensor
>   b (32) at non-singleton dimension 1**

How can I reshape the tensor, and which tensor (output or labels) should I change to calculate the loss?

Entire code is attached below.

```
import numpy as np
import torch

# Loading the Fashion-MNIST dataset
from torchvision import datasets, transforms

# Get GPU Device
device = torch.device("cuda:0" if torch.cuda.is_available() else "cpu")

transform = transforms.Compose([transforms.ToTensor(),
                                    transforms.Normalize((0.5,), (0.5,))])
# Download and load the training data
trainset = datasets.FashionMNIST('MNIST_data/', download = True, train = True, transform = transform)
testset = datasets.FashionMNIST('MNIST_data/', download = True, train = False, transform = transform)
trainloader = torch.utils.data.DataLoader(trainset, batch_size = 32, shuffle = True, num_workers=4)
testloader = torch.utils.data.DataLoader(testset, batch_size = 32, shuffle = True, num_workers=4)

# Examine a sample
dataiter = iter(trainloader)
images, labels = dataiter.next()

# Define the network architecture
from torch import nn, optim
import torch.nn.functional as F

model = nn.Sequential(nn.Linear(784, 128),
                      nn.ReLU(),
                      nn.Linear(128, 10),
                      nn.LogSoftmax(dim = 1))
model.to(device)

# Define the loss
criterion = nn.MSELoss()

# Define the optimizer
optimizer = optim.Adam(model.parameters(), lr = 0.001)

# Define the epochs
epochs = 5

train_losses, test_losses = [], []

for e in range(epochs):
  running_loss = 0
  for images, labels in trainloader:
    # Flatten Fashion-MNIST images into a 784 long vector
    images = images.to(device)
    labels = labels.to(device)
    images = images.view(images.shape[0], -1)

    # Training pass
    optimizer.zero_grad()
    output = model.forward(images)
    print(output.shape, labels.shape)
    loss = criterion(output, labels)
    loss.backward()
    optimizer.step()

    running_loss += loss.item()
  else:
    test_loss = 0
    accuracy = 0

    # Turn off gradients for validation, saves memory and computation
    with torch.no_grad():
      # Set the model to evaluation mode
      model.eval()

      # Validation pass
      for images, labels in testloader:
        images = images.to(device)
        labels = labels.to(device)
        images = images.view(images.shape[0], -1)
        ps = model(images)
        test_loss += criterion(ps, labels)
        top_p, top_class = ps.topk(1, dim = 1)
        equals = top_class == labels.view(*top_class.shape)
        accuracy += torch.mean(equals.type(torch.FloatTensor))

    model.train()

    print("Epoch: {}/{}..".format(e+1, epochs),
          "Training loss: {:.3f}..".format(running_loss/len(trainloader)),
          "Test loss: {:.3f}..".format(test_loss/len(testloader)),
          "Test Accuracy: {:.3f}".format(accuracy/len(testloader)))
```

Comment: Put all the error log not just the last line

Comment: @NatthaphonHongcharoen Thank you for your comment. I attached the entire lines of the error message.

Answer (score 2):

From the output you print before it error, `torch.Size([32, 10]) torch.Size([32])`.

The left one is what the model gives you and the right one is from `trainloader`, normally you use this for something like `nn.CrossEntropyLoss`.

And from the full error log, the error is from this line

```
loss = criterion(output, labels)
```

The way to make this work is called One-hot Encoding, if it's me for sake of my laziness I'll write it like this.

```
ones = torch.sparse.torch.eye(10).to(device)  # number of class class
labels = ones.index_select(0, labels)
```

Comment: Thank you for your kind explanation. However, it gives me another hardship saying "Expected object of device type cuda but got device type cpu for argument #1 'self' in call to _th_index_select"

This error if from the line "labels = ones.index_select(0, labels)"

Comment: I edited the answer, actually just put `to(device)` after the `ones =`. See if that's work.

Answer (score 0):

Alternatively, you can change your loss function from `nn.MSELoss()` to `nn.CrossEntropyLoss()`. Cross entropy loss is generally preferable to MSE for categorical tasks like this, and in PyTorch's implementation this loss function takes care of a lot of the shape conversion under the hood so you can provide it with a vector of class probabilities and a single class label.

Fundamentally, your model attempts to predict what class the input belongs to by calculating a score (you might call it a 'confidence score') for each possible class. So if you have 10 classes, the model's output will be a 10-dimensional list (in PyTorch, a tensor shape `[10]`) and the prediction would be the the index of the highest score. Often one would apply the softmax (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Softmax_function) function to convert these scores to a probability distribution, so all scores will be between 0 and 1 and the elements all sum to 1.

Then cross entropy is a common choice of loss function for this task: it compares the list of predictions to the one-hot encoded label. E.g. if you have 3 classes, a label would look like `[1, 0, 0]` to represent the first class. This is also called the "one-hot encoding". Meanwhile a prediction might look like `[0.7, 0.1, 0.2]`. In PyTorch, `nn.CrossEntropyLoss()` expects your labels are coming as single value tensors whose value represents the class label, since there's no real need to move long, sparse vectors around memory. So this loss function accomplishes the comparison you want to do and I'm guessing is implemented more efficiently than actually creating one-hot encodings.